# Average of positive and negative part of numpy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I’ve got a matrix of data and I want to take the average of the positive and negative parts of the values.
Is there a more Pythonic way of doing it?

```
from numpy import *

…

exposures = matrix([0]*numPaths*numExposures)
exposures.shape = numPaths, numExposures

… # fill matrix

@vectorize
def plusv(x): return max(x,0)

@vectorize
def minv(x): return min(x,0)

ee  = transpose(exposures.mean(axis=0))
epe = transpose(plusv(exposures).mean(axis=0))
ene = transpose(minv(exposures).mean(axis=0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things which we could improve:

When importing a module, you would not usually import all symbols from that module. You can however rename the module to make it more convenient, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
# now we can do np.matrix(…), np.transpose(…), etc.
```

Instead of initializing a matrix and then reshaping it, create it directly in the shape you need:

```
exposures = np.zeros((numPaths, numExposures))
```

When `def`ining a function put the function body on a new line, no matter how short it might be:

```
def plusv(x):
    return max(x, 0)
```

Instead of stuffing this normalization into a custom function, you could just use the builtin `clip`. It takes two arguments: a minimum and maximum bound, both inclusive. So `plusv(a)` would be equivalent to `a.clip(0, np.inf)` for floats and `a.clip(0, np.iinfo(np.int).max)` for integers.

The numpy functions can either be called as functions or as methods. Using them as methods is usually easier to read for people used to reading left-to-right.

```
ee  = exposures.mean(axis=0).transpose()
epe = exposures.clip(0, np.inf).mean(axis=0).transpose()
ene = exposures.clip(-np.inf, 0).mean(axis=0).transpose()
```

Oh dear, we are repeating code! Well, let's just use a list comprehension/generator expression instead:

```
positive_exposures = exposures.clip(0, np.inf)
negative_exposures = exposures.clip(-np.inf, 0)
ee, epe, ene = (xs.mean(axis=0).transpose() for xs in
    (exposures, positive_exposures, negative_exposures))
```

In the above snippet, the temporary variables `positive_exposure` and `negative_exposure` are entirely optional, but they make the code more *self-documenting*.

Note that I use `snake_case` for my variables. This is the convention in Python for normal variables or method names. The `lowerCamelCase` scheme is not generally used. While I recommend you follow the general Python convention of words separated by underscores, the only important thing is to be consistent. Whatever your naming scheme, names like `ee` and `epe` are *not acceptable*. Prefer full words over abbreviations, unless the abbreviations are common enough (`i` for an index is ok, and everyone understands `str` means “string“).